# includeProperties not working?

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, struts2-json-plugin

**struts.xml:**

```
<action name="findTspNameIdMap"
            class="cdot.oss.cmsat.gma.struts.ConfigureTspThresholdAction" method="findTspNameIdMap">

            <result name="success" type="json">
                <param name="includeProperties">result,tspNameIdMap.*</param>   
            </result> 

            <result name="error">pages/Error.jsp</result>

        </action>
```

**Action class:**

```
public class ConfigureTspThresholdAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware, ModelDriven<GmaThresholdParameter>{


    private Map<String,Object> session;
    private String operatorId;

    private Map<String,String> tspNameIdMap;
    private String result = "success";

    //private List<String> thresholdParameters;
    GmaThresholdParameter gmaThresholdParameters = new GmaThresholdParameter();
```

I do an AJAX call to the action, when I check in Firebug the JSON response it is: `{}` .
However if I do `<param name="root">tspNameIdMap</param>` it works but not `includeProperties`.

Earlier it was working but I made some code changes(not related to this above part of the code) and it stopped working. Code changes included implementing `ModelDriven` for a POJO.

Why is not working? Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

**struts.xml:**

```
   <result name="success" type="json">
        <param name="root">action</param>         
        <param name="includeProperties">result,tspNameIdMap.*</param>   
    </result-type>
```

I added `<param name="root">action</param>` to my code and it solved the problem.

Refer to this link from where I solved: http://blog.mattsch.com/2011/04/14/things-discovered-in-struts-2/

> Since Struts 2.2.3 the root object is always considered to be the model if the action is model >driven. This means that when creating the JSON request only the model will get serialized. In >some cases one might use model driven for receiving requests and send something else in the >response. Then the root object has to be changed. This can be done by setting the root >parameter as shown above.

Comment: How OGNL could find an `action` object?

Comment: The action is on the value stack but you can't access it with this expression.

Comment: So, what object is returned by the value stack and from where?

Comment: It's a good question, first I tried to find out looking at this answer. But I'd like to disclose it, of course if you won't put your comment here.

Comment: The `valueStack` is trying to find a value by the expression via OGNL, and if it can't find it, it gets it from the "value stack context" by the key.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<result name="success" type="json">      
    <param name="includeProperties">result,tspNameIdMap*.*</param>   
</result-type>
```

Following param is not required , I found same result with and without this

```
<param name="root">action</param>
```